# Problems with nested lambdas in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, lambda

Does anyone know why this code is not compilable with VC++ 2010

```
class C
{
public:
    void M(string t) {}
    void M(function<string()> func) {}
};

void TestMethod(function<void()> func) {}

void TestMethod2()    
{
    TestMethod([] () {
        C c;            
        c.M([] () -> string { // compiler error C2668 ('function' : ambiguous call to overloaded function)

             return ("txt");
        });
    });
}
```

**Update:**

Full code example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
  void M(string t) {}
  void M(function<string()> func) {}
};

void TestMethod(function<void()> func) {}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   TestMethod([] () {
      C c;
      c.M([] () -> string { // compiler erorr C2668 ('function' : ambiguous call to overloaded function M)
          return ("txt");
      });
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay. So what does C2668 say? Not everyone is using that compiler.

Comment: Sorry. I added the error description above

Comment: The version I posted below compiles cleanly with g++. You should post your actual code.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete. To use `string`, you shall `#include <string>`. Also, the standard compatible `main` has the signature `int main()` or `int main(int, char*[])`. Everything else is compiler specific.

Comment: Btw, what else have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of the VC++ Compiler.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687935/ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function-in-c-when-using-lambdas

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the error message, so by looking into my crystal ball I can only conclude that you suffer those problems:

### Missing #includes

You need at the top

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
```

### Missing name qualifications

You either need to add

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::string; using std::function;
```

or
    std::function ...
    std::string ...

### Missing function `main()`

```
int main() {}
```

### Works with g++

```
foo@bar: $ cat nested-lambda.cc

#include <string>
#include <functional>

class C
{
public:
    void M(std::string t) {}
    void M(std::function<std::string()> func) {}
};

void TestMethod(std::function<void()> func) {}

void TestMethod2()    
{
    TestMethod([] () {
        C c;            
        c.M([] () -> std::string { // compiler error C2668 
             return ("txt");
        });
    });
}

int main() {
}

foo@bar: $ g++ -std=c++0x nested-lambda.cc
```

Works fine.

Comment: I posted the error number (and now the error message too) as source code comment.  My problem is, that the compiler doesn't know which method overload of M should be used. But I don't know why. You said that the code compiles correct with g++, so maybe it's a VC++ compiler bug.

Comment: or a bug in g++, maybe it's not supposed to but g++ does; though for the life of me I can't see why VC++ wouldn't handle it. g++ has bugs as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214623/c0x-rule-for-lambda-capture-variable

Comment: @Shaun Wilde: The body of a lambda is a `compound-statement`, which is the same for ordinary functions, where the body is a `compound-statement`, too (see Annex A: Grammar summary). And of course every non-trivial software has bugs ;)

Comment: @phresnal - the code above (in question body) doesn't compile in VC++ as the questioner described. Is it supposed to, as it does in g++, if so then it is a bug in vc++?

Comment: @Shaun Wilde: It also depends on the rest of the code that the OP did not post. However, I guess it is a bug in VC++ indeed.